# How to display binary image in react using canvas and useRefs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I have a mock RGBA image in the form [255, 0, 0, 255] and I want to display it on my webpage using react.

```
mockImageArray = [255, 0, 0, 255];
var mockImage = new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(mockImageArray), 1, 1);

const Canvas = (props) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  const draw = (ctx) => {
    var imageData = ctx.createImageData(mockImage);

    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 256;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    draw(context);
  }, [draw]);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} {...props} />;
};
```

I'm expecting a red pixel when I load this component in the main component, however, I can't seem to load anything. Elements don't even show up in the elements tab. Could someone guide me as to where I'm going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: [255, 0, 0, 255], i'll update the code to make it clearer. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the MDN, [`createImageData` doesn't copy the image data from the buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createImageData).

> `imagedata`
> An existing ImageData object from which to copy the width and height. The image itself is not copied.

You don't need to create a separate `imageData` anyway;

```
ctx.putImageData(mockImage, 20, 20);
```

works just fine (moved to 20,20 since it's easier to see).

Comment: Yep, it was just the positioning. Thank you!